# VFD as general use inverter

Tags: ac, three-phase, vfd

I'd like to have 3ph 208 in my house for general use (not a motor). If I run the output of a single phase to 3 phase VFD through inductors or a 1:1 transformer will it smooth the SPWM .output into an accurate sine wave?.

Comment: This is unlikely to work well. VFDs are optimised for driving motors which can tolerate the PWM outputs. Usually the only reason for requiring three-phase is to drive three-phase motors. If that is your situation then just put the VFDs on the motors.

Comment: @Transistor It would mostly be for a 3 phase DC supply.

Comment: 3phase DC supply oO

Comment: @JonRB A DC supply that runs on 3 phase 208V

Comment: Changing to a single-phase DC supply should be less expensive than using a VFD. If you have a VFD that you don's need for anything else, you could probably get DC from that or hack it to make a DC supply. If your DC supply has a controlled rectifier, the VFD may not like that as a load. It may not like an uncontrolled rectifier load either. I don't think there is any way for this to avoid being a bad idea.

Comment: @CharlesCowie thanks, that may be the best option. A lot of the multi kilowatt variable supplies available seem to be 3ph 208, but there must be some 240 ones available too. I think they all have PFC.

Comment: Given that VFD's have to be de-rated for single phase usage given the decreased capability of the rectifiers and capacitors that form their DC rail when fed with only a single phase, perhaps what you really should do is find an oversized DC supply that the manufacturer is willing to de-rate for single phase usage.   All you are really doing by throwing in the VFD is *moving the problem* to the VFD's DC bus - and throwing in additional problems, too.

Comment: You can use the VFD to run a motor. And have the motor run a 3-phase generator head. There is also a technique to use a 3-phase motor as a 3-phase power source. You have to spin up the motor somehow (with a pilot motor for example) then connect single-phase to the 3-phase motor. The motor will continue to spin and generate the missing phases itself. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Singe phase can be converted in to three phase using VFD drive by changing algorithm and adding some filters at output.

Comment: That's fairly irrelevant to the actual problem.  It's not like the asker is going to go change the firmware.